# How to create a Submit & Close button in SharePoint Powerapps Form

Tags: modern-experience, powerapps-forms, button, submit

I'm trying to create a survey based on a list in SharePoint modern.  I am creating it in a form (because there isn't a Survey web part I can find here), and customizing the form in PowerApps.  I just need to know how to add the actions of Submit and Close to a button.  Here's what I'm looking at:

[image]

Let's just say the "Next" button is on my final screen.  What do I do to apply a Submit/Save and Close to the button.  The users will navigate to the list and open the form as the survey, so I want their results to display on the list.  But I can't figure out how to set this action.  It was very straight forward in InfoPath, but I can't use that here.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to store each Question result as a new item? Or store all results in a single list item?

Comment: I'm storing each answer in a single list item.  The fields are the columns I created in the list, so I'd like the answers populated there once I click the Submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form is attached to a list use RequestHide() [Nothing in parens] to close.
ResetForm(SharePointForm1) will just clear the form and you will still have to use the built in cancel to hide the form.

Answer (score 1):

Submit: `SubmitForm(SharePointForm1)`

Close: `ResetForm(SharePointForm1)`

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/sharepoint-form-integration